# Error when show API data. Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am developing Currency Converter application using ReactJS. The program is about convert from one currency to another. The application has one form consist of a field with submit button. Moreover it also has initial currency 'USD 10' as a default.

When user type the an abbreviation of currency (e.g.: KRW) in the field and click the submit button. There will be a result below the form that shows the result of the conversion from USD to KRW. If the user want to add more currency, another selection currency will be shown below "KRW" conversion result.

When I am trying to make function to show the result when user submit the abbreviation of currency in the field. 
[image: the application UI]

This is the error when I open in the chrome console:

```
    index.js:1375 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `CurrencyList`. See https://.. for more information.
    in Currency (at App.js:249)
    in CurrencyList (at App.js:159)
    in div (at App.js:127)
    in div (at App.js:123)
    in App (at src/index.js:7)
```

And this is my code related at App.js:249

```
class CurrencyList extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const p = this.props;
        return (
            <div className="currencyList">
                <span className="currencyListText">&#x3C;CurrencyList/&#x3E;<br/></span>
                {p.currencyInfoArray.map(currencyInfo => <Currency key={currencyInfo.id} {...currencyInfo}/>)} //this is App.js:249

            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Regarding that, how can I solve the problem so that each child in a list will have a unique "key" prop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is some common solutions:

1. Use Id of Database

When you get data from database it's better to use unique id of them so you dont need to generate it.in this example if currencyInfoArray comes from a table in array just get ids from backend and give it to reactjs.

2. generate Unique Id

there is some modules that do it for you like: [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid)

3. use id of array:

something like this:

```
                {p.currencyInfoArray.map((currencyInfo,idx) => <Currency key={idx} {...currencyInfo}/>)} //this is App.js:249
```

at last check your id's with React Developer Tools in chrome and check everything is true.
feel free to ask more questions in comment

Comment: 1. Is the solution will same if I do not use database? I just retrive data from API dan put it on the array.

Comment: check your data. Is there any unique id in them? if there is you can use it, if not you should generate it with another ways.

Comment: May I ask for this I have same error for this syntax. `{Object.keys(p.rates).map(function(key, idx) {
                        return <div>Key: {key}, Covertion Value: {p.rates[key]}</div>;
                    })}` . Do you have any idea for this? Sorry for asking again..

Comment: sure, just change your syntax to this:{Object.keys(p.rates).map(function(key, idx) { return <div key: {key} >Key: {key}, Covertion Value: {p.rates[key]}</div>; })}

Comment: thanks, however when I used the update code there is an error `Parsing error: Unexpected token` in here `<div key: {key} >`. Any Idea?